# In OpenLayers, Getting 1 Layer to stay over the other. (Z-Axis)

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I have this map, which I show some **red** markers over and whenever a location is chosen from a list the current marker is painted **blue** and the map centers around it.

I achieve this by having 2 layers - one for the red markers which is drawn at the beginning and one which is redrawn whenever a point is chosen from the list.
[image]

I would like to define that the **red** marker layer will always appear above the **blue** marker layer. Effectively hiding the "current marker" indication. (The reason for this is complicated)

[This link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80497/htmlTesting/osm3_basic_shortened.html) is to a page that works the way I don't want. The blue layer is on top of the red layer.
I tried to reverse the order by defining the `graphicZIndex` property for both the vector and in the `layers.addFeature` function.

I'm obviously doing something wrong and maybe someone can point me to what it is.
The way I define the z-axis:

```
        currentPointLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selected Point Layer", {
            style : {
                externalGraphic : 'marker-blue.png',
                graphicHeight : 15,
                graphicWidth : 15,
                graphicZIndex : 1
            },
            rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true }
        });
```

**Again**, I want to hide the blue marker behind the red markers layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the order of your layers as ilia choly stated.

Or, if you want to use zIndexing, you have to put all features into **one layer**, because zIndexing is only done within a single layer.

Have a look at [this simple example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/stylemap.html) about styling, that also uses zIndexing. It randomly creates some points in the map. If you zoom out, chances are good that two circles overlap and if you hoover over one, it will be highlighted and put on top.

Answer (score 2):

So you want highlight a marker with different color whenever a point is selected? Managing it with 2 layers is really an overkill. You should be able to define a vector layer with style like this:

```
var currentPointLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selected Point Layer", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        externalGraphic : '${markerUrl}',
        pointRadius: 20
})});
map.addLayer(currentPointLayer);
```

Then you have to set attribute 'markerUrl' of every feature(i.e. feature.attributes.markerUrl) to 'marker-red.png' - that would be initial state of all features.

Then whenever feature is selected you change markerUrl attribute of selected feature to 'marker-blue.png' and(important) call

> currentPointLayer.redraw();

Obviously you'll also have to set previously selected feature to 'marker-red.png' when new feature is selected.

Comment: Tnx! I chose to implement your solution.
Since it doesn't specifically answer the question I couldn't mark it as the solution (But i Uppd it :-) )

Comment: Does this apply if I use 1 feature that includes all the markers or do I have to create a feature for every marker on the map?
How can I apply a style per marker if I have 1 feature?

Comment: Unless I used MultiPoint in a Vector... Never mind, I changed the code to use Point per feature.. (tnx)

Answer (score 1):

in your `init_map()` function you're adding the red marker layer before the blue ones. Try switching them.

```
preparePointsOnMap(map, points); //red marker

if (!map.getCenter()) {
    map_set_center(lon, lat, mZoom); //blue marker
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That specifically replaces the order but I am looking for a solution that would not be based on the order of placement of layers but on z-axis (graphicZIndex) properties.

If no such solution exists than I will mark your answer as the solution.